# Not able to create event on Calendar with this script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I have the title for event, start date and end date in Google Sheet cell U69, U70, X69 respectively.

It says execution successful in script but events are not getting added.

```
function calendar() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("c_v6h2ud0dru0dqojch3103sue20@group.calendar.google.com");
  var name = spreadsheet.getRange('U69').getValue();
  var start = new Date(spreadsheet.getRange('U70').getValue());
  var end =  new Date(spreadsheet.getRange('X69').getValue());
  eventCal.createEvent(name,start,end);

  Logger.log('Reminder is added to your calendar');
}
```

**Edit 2:**

PS - I am doing it on a sheet, of whom I am the owner. I am also creating the script. I am running it and I can't see entry on calendar.
5 people have access to that sheet. I have given access to all 5 - "Make Changes and manage sharing" from the calendar settings section.

Pls help. What am I doing wrong? Where is the syntax error? Am I putting the quotes for the variables correctly? or is it something else?

**Edit 3:**
I added logger.log(calendar). It says execution successful (as per image attached) in script but the event is not getting added.

```
function calendar() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("AA69").getValue();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("c_v6h2ud0dru0dqojch3103sue20@group.calendar.google.com");

  var name = spreadsheet.getRange('U69').getValue();
  var start = new Date(spreadsheet.getRange('U70').getValue());
  var end =  new Date(spreadsheet.getRange('X69').getValue());
  eventCal.createEvent(name,start,end);
  Logger.log(calendarId);
}
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

**Edit 4:**
I checked with ISDATE() formula. Both U70 and X69 are True. The code also shows execution done. Logger.Log also gives correct cell value.

What should I do with syntax nw? event is still not getting added.

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Course');
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('c_v6h2ud0dru0dqojch3103sue20@group.calendar.google.com');
  var name = spreadsheet.getRange('U69').getValue();  

  var start = spreadsheet.getRange('U70').getDisplayValue(); 
  var end = spreadsheet.getRange('X69').getDisplayValue();
  eventCal.createEvent(name,new Date(start),new Date(end));
  Logger.log(end);
}
```

**Edit 5:**
Mike's answer has helped me. Thank you so much, Mike

Comment: Check the user your authorized as.  I question if its inserting into the calendar you think it is.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I did not understand the comment. What user and how do I check it? Pls help. Not from a coding background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code that works fine in 3 ways getCalendarsByName, getCalendarById, getDefaultCalendar

```
function testCalendar() { 
  
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var start = new Date(sh.getRange('A1').getValue()).getTime()
  var end = new Date(sh.getRange('A2').getValue()).getTime()

  var calendName = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName('alertes');
  var calendById = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('a2j9469bvfr93ob9bbottd0v80@group.calendar.google.com')
  var calend = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar()

  calendName[0].createEvent('test script createEvent', new Date(start), new Date(end)).addSmsReminder(0); 
  calendById.createEvent('test script createEvent', new Date(start), new Date(end)).addSmsReminder(0);   
  calend.createEvent('test script createEvent', new Date(start), new Date(end)).addSmsReminder(0);   

}
```

so, I suggest you to try

```
function calendar() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("c_v6h2ud0dru0dqojch3103sue20@group.calendar.google.com");
  var name = spreadsheet.getRange('U69').getValue();
  var start = new Date(spreadsheet.getRange('U70').getValue()).getTime();
  var end =  new Date(spreadsheet.getRange('X69').getValue()).getTime();
  eventCal.createEvent(name,new Date(start),new Date(end));
  Logger.log('Reminder is added to your calendar');
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Here is my new requirement related to this same question. Pls help Link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71359532/add-calendar-event-with-the-help-of-checkbox

Comment: Sorry, the question is already closed!

Comment: Mike, the question is open now. My struggling again. Made real efforts but strange things are happening. My syntax and logic is not working.

Comment: @user18308583, let's focus on one question per post. If your initial question is answered, do not add questions to it. Post another one.

Comment: I am sorry for this. I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are having `eventCal.createEvent...... TypeError: Cannot read property 'createEvent' of null` is `CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendar id)` returns **null** if the calendar does not exist, if the user cannot access it, or if the user is not subscribed to the calendar.

To solve the issue, make sure you have edit access to the calendar and rerun your code. If you have access to the calendar it should return a **Calendar Class** and inside that Calendar class is the `createEvent()` method.

### Update #1:

Given that the OP is also the owner of the calendar, one possible reason is that the value of `var calendarId` is not a valid id for calendar. You can try to debug it by adding `Logger.log(calendarId)` below it to check if you were able to fetch the value of calendar ID  in cell **AA69**.

Follow this link on [how to get the calendar ID](https://docs.simplecalendar.io/find-google-calendar-id/).

### Update #2:

For date issue here are the options you can take:

- Remove the `new Date()` in `start` and `end` variables.

or

- use `getDisplayValue()` instead of `getValue()`.

### References:

- [getCalendarById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getcalendarbyidid)
- [Class Calendar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar)

Comment: Hi Nikko, pls help me. I have added EDIT 4 in my question.

Comment: @user18308583 - I updated my answer. Let me know if it works. Also, providing a sample spreadsheet would be helpful.

Comment: Nikko J, thank you so much. Mike's code has worked for me. Thank you again for the efforts.