# Add calendar event with the help of checkbox

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

With reference to this question - [Not able to create event on Calendar with this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71354741/not-able-to-create-event-on-calendar-with-this-script)

**The Code after all changes:**

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('⇩ M E N U ⇩')
    .addItem(' Set up ...', 'myTriggerSetup')
    .addToUi();
}
function myTriggerSetup() {
  var ssID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()
  if (!isTrigger('onSpeEdit')) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('onSpeEdit').forSpreadsheet(ssID).onEdit().create();
  }
}
function isTrigger(funcName) {
  var r = false;
  if (funcName) {
    var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    var allHandlers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < allTriggers.length; i++) {
      allHandlers.push(allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction());
    }
    if (allHandlers.indexOf(funcName) > -1) {
      r = true;
    }
  }
  return r;
}
function onSpeEdit(e) {
  var rg = e.range;
  if (rg.getRow() == 57 && rg.isChecked() && rg.getSheet().getName() === "Course") {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Course');
  var start = new Date(spreadsheet.getRange('U70').getValue()).getTime();
  var end = new Date(spreadsheet.getRange('X69').getValue()).getTime();
  var name = spreadsheet.getRange('U69').getValue()
  var calend = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  calend.createEvent(name, new Date(start), new Date(end));
    rg.uncheck();
  }
}
```

**My Requirement:**
A user will fill all 3 cells for event details. Then, they will tick on checkbox and the event should get added and also checkbox should get untick. Then, another user will do the same process again.

**My Issues:**
It is working in the dummy sheet but not in main sheet.My above code is as per main sheet.

**Dummy Sheet:**  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_f_dujqIvmkXXLAqyandEmrWOxgskIfk9KTSKw28UuA/edit#gid=0

**Thank you:**
Thank you, Mike and Tanaike for the amazing efforts to help me.

Comment: I think that the situation is the same with this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/q/71215657/7108653 In your script, when `calendar()` works fine, the reason for your issue is due to that you try to use `alendarApp.getDefaultCalendar()` using a simple trigger. By this, an error occurs. I think that this is the reason for `but not by checkbox.`. In this case, please use the installable trigger instead of the simple trigger, and test it again.

Comment: Thanks but I cannot understand your solution. I am not from coding background. Can you please post a code as solution or a change. It will be get solution.  Pls do not mark it closed as I cannot understand the link provided.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. In my answer, I have explained the situation. Can you confirm it? In your situation, 1. Rename the function name of `onEdit` to `installedOnEdit`. 2. Install the installable OnEdit trigger to the renamed function. By this, when you check the checkbox, the script is run. If you cannot understand it, I apologize again.

Comment: I understand English but I am not from coding background. I cannot understand the solution. I did step 1. Now, what is the meaning of "Install the installable OnEdit trigger". Can you paste the entire working code? Pls. Request you to please not close the question.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. I have explained the method for using the installable trigger at my answer. But from `but I am not from coding background. I cannot understand the solution. I did step 1. Now, what is the meaning of "Install the installable OnEdit trigger". Can you paste the entire working code?`, I posted it as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If you cannot still understand my answer. I apologize again.

Comment: Hello @user18308583, has your question been answered - did the answer below solve your problem? If not, what name does the sheet from the main spreadsheet have?

Comment: Hi. Yes, it did. Thank you everyone for all the efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('⇩ M E N U ⇩')
    .addItem(' Set up ...', 'myTriggerSetup')
    .addToUi();
}
function myTriggerSetup() {
  var ssID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()
  if (!isTrigger('onSpeEdit')) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('onSpeEdit').forSpreadsheet(ssID).onEdit().create();
  }
}
function isTrigger(funcName) {
  var r = false;
  if (funcName) {
    var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    var allHandlers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < allTriggers.length; i++) {
      allHandlers.push(allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction());
    }
    if (allHandlers.indexOf(funcName) > -1) {
      r = true;
    }
  }
  return r;
}
function onSpeEdit(e) {
  var rg = e.range;
  if (rg.getRow() == 4 && rg.isChecked() && rg.getSheet().getName() === "Course") {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Course');
    var start = new Date(rg.offset(-2,0).getValue()).getTime();
    var end = new Date(rg.offset(-1,0).getValue()).getTime();
    var name = rg.offset(-3,0).getValue();
    var calend = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
    calend.createEvent(name, new Date(start), new Date(end));
    rg.uncheck();
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked like a magic in testing sheet. But Mike, I copy pasted in the main sheet it gives error = TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined ( Line no is var rg = e.range..This one)

Comment: How do you run the script ? Do you run by "execute" in the script editor ? or within a button ?

Comment: In this order >>> First, I pasted full code in the editor. Selected all the 4 functions. Clicked on Run. Then, I went to excel sheet and checked on the box to see if events are getting added.

Comment: Hi Mike, I have added the code in the question part which i pasted in my editor. When I select all 4 functions and run it, it shows no error. When I run the from custom menu, it shows no error. But calendar events are not getting added now/even with ticks in checkbox they are not getting added.

Comment: Do you see MENU at top right of the menu of the spreadsheet ? If yes, click on set up. Then you just have to check one checkbox at a time. If you don't see the menu, close and reopen the spreadsheet. May be click again in setup a second time.

Comment: The function only run when you click on checkbox. You do not have to execute within the script editor.

Comment: Check if your tab is weel 'Course' without any extra space at the end of the word.

Comment: Mike, I followed your steps and now it is working like magic, as always. But a big issue! When other users of that sheet are following the steps, the events are getting added to my calendar (and not their default calendar). What should be done now? (When I tested with just the simple calendar function (ur previous solution) and assigned it a button, all users were getting events on their calendar)

Comment: um, of course, you are the proprietary of the script. I'm not sure how to fix this issue, maybe post a separate topic.

Comment: may be 2 solutions : 1/ duplicate the spreadsheet and give a sample to each person 2/ create multiples calendars inside your own calendar and add a cell to get the name of the person, then use `var calendName = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName('somebody');`

Comment: I changed the code and use the same var calend = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar(); Now, it is adding in mine as well as user's .Link to the question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71365406/events-are-getting-added-to-two-default-calendar-mine-as-well-other-users-of-t

Comment: Mike, one issue/question with this code. The trigger is set to fire on "Edit of any cell". Hence, the trigger is running on every edit on the sheet to check if my checkbox is ticked? Is it so? The sheet has many data and users are changing it every min. Can you set the. trigger to fire ONLY AND ONLY if checkbox in row 57 is ticked. Pls. I want to limit the use of triggers on the sheet.

Comment: Trigger will only run when `if (rg.getRow() == 4 && rg.isChecked() && rg.getSheet().getName() === "Course")` so when ths sheet name is Course, the row is 4 and the value is true according to your dummy sheet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242648/discussion-between-user18308583-and-mike-steelson).

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Rename your function name as follows.

In this case, you can also use the other function names except for `onEdit`. About the reason of this, you can see it at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71215657/7108653).

```
function installedOnEdit(e){
  var rg = e.range;
  if(rg.getA1Notation() === "Z56" && rg.isChecked() && rg.getSheet().getName() === "Course"){
    calendar(); //calling calendar function
    rg.uncheck()
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Course').getRange('X57').setValue('Event has been added to your Calendar')//Putting message in cell x57;
  }
}
```

#### 2. Install the installable OnEdit trigger to the renamed function.

You can see how to manually install this at [the official document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually).

If you are required to use a script, you can also the following script.

```
function installTrigger() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("installedOnEdit").forSpreadsheet(ss).onEdit().create();
}
```

By this flow, `installedOnEdit` is run by the installable OnEdit trigger. When you use this, please check the checkbox. By this, `installedOnEdit` is run and `CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar()` is run.

#### Note:

- In this case, it supposes that your `calendar()` and the if statement in `onEdit` works fine. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

### Added:

I saw your provided sample Spreadsheet. When I saw it, the values of "Name", "Start Date", "End Date", "Add to Calendar" are the cells "B1:B4". But in your script, those values are not used. I think that your new issue is due to this. Please modify your script using your sample Spreadsheet as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function calendar() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Course');
  var start = new Date(spreadsheet.getRange('B2').getValue()).getTime();
  var end = new Date(spreadsheet.getRange('B3').getValue()).getTime();
  var name = spreadsheet.getRange('B1').getValue()

  var calend = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  calend.createEvent(name, new Date(start), new Date(end));
}

function installedOnEdit(e) {
  var rg = e.range;
  if (rg.getA1Notation() === "B4" && rg.isChecked() && rg.getSheet().getName() === "Course") {
    calendar(); //calling calendar function
    rg.uncheck();
  }
}

function installTrigger() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("installedOnEdit").forSpreadsheet(ss).onEdit().create();
}
```

- In this case, when the installable OnEdit trigger is installed by `installTrigger()`, when the checkbox of cell "B4" is checked, the event is created.

Comment: Thank you so much for this but it is not working as expected. My need is 1_User fills all details and clicks on checkbox then event should be added and checkbox should get unticked on its own. 2_Second user will then fill details and click on checkbox and event will get added and so on.

Comment: I think there is mistake here itself - function installedOnEdit(e) is not working as desired. The "if" part

Comment: @user18308583 Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, about `My need is 1_User fills all details and clicks on checkbox then event should be added and checkbox should get unticked on its own. 2_Second user will then fill details and click on checkbox and event will get added and so on.`, I cannot see this in your question. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal? By this, I would like to try to understand your question. By the way, I supposes that your `calendar()` and the if statement in `onEdit` works fine. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: The function function installTrigger() should only run if edit is in Z56, that is if someone checks the box in Z56. How do you do that? Some changes here -   ScriptApp.newTrigger("installedOnEdit").forSpreadsheet(ss).onEdit().create();
} ??

Comment: @user18308583 Thank you for replying. You want to run `calendar()` when a checkbox of cell "Z56" of "Course" sheet is checked. Is my understanding correct? About `Some changes here - ScriptApp.newTrigger("installedOnEdit").forSpreadsheet(ss).onEdit().create(); } ??`, I cannot understand what you want to say. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: @user18308583 Now, I noticed that you had updated your question. When I saw your updated question, your function name is `InstallonEdit`. If you use my proposed script for installing the OnEdit trigger, `installedOnEdit` should be modified to `InstalledOnEdit`. If you had manually installed the OnEdit trigger, I think that the correct function name is used. And, if you want to use `function InstallonEdit(e){}`, when this function is installed as the OnEdit trigger, when the checkbox of "Z56" is checked, `calendar()` can run. When you test it, what result will you obtain?

Comment: I have modified my question and written it in detailed. Pls help.

Comment: @user18308583 Thank you for replying. I have to deeply apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, your updated question doesn't reflect my comment. In your updated script, function name is `InstallonEdit`. If you use my proposed script for installing the OnEdit trigger, `installedOnEdit` should be modified to `InstalledOnEdit`. If you had manually installed the OnEdit trigger, I think that the correct function name is used.

Comment: @user18308583 By the way, if you want to use `function InstallonEdit(e){}`, when this function is installed as the OnEdit trigger, when the checkbox of "Z56" is checked, `calendar()` can run. Can you confirm whether your function of `InstallonEdit` is installed as the OnEdit trigger and test it again? By the way, when you cannot understand my English, I apologize.

Comment: @user18308583 Now, I noticed that you had updated your question. When I saw your updated script, in this case, you changed the function name to `function installedonEdit(e){}`. But you try to install the function name of `installedOnEdit`. In this case, the trigger is not run. When you want to use `function installedonEdit(e){}`. Please install the function name of `installedonEdit`.

Comment: @user18308583 By the way, when your function is correctly installed as the OnEdit trigger, I could confirm that your script works. So, I think that your current issue is due to the install of OnEdit trigger.

Comment: The code is not working. Here is the sheet = https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_f_dujqIvmkXXLAqyandEmrWOxgskIfk9KTSKw28UuA/edit#gid=0 Pls pls pls help

Comment: @user18308583 I saw your provided sample Spreadsheet. In your script, the cells and the variables are not matched. I think that this is the reason for your new issue. For this, I added a modified script using your provided script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: I confirm that the code provided by Tanaike is right, may be a slight modiication on your hand. To help you, I have added a menu. Thx to Tanaike

Comment: It could be interresting to integrate calendar() function.

Comment: @Mike Steelson Thank you for checking it and for your support. I think that I have to study English more in order to correctly understand and clearly explain.

Comment: @Tanaike, I really appreciate all your works, it's great, and I don't think that the langage is blocking. I am French and not very famailiar with English too. I usually study all the answers you are providing here.

Comment: @Mike Steelson I appreciate it. And, I'm honored for it. Your comment is encouraging for me. I'll keep up my work!

Comment: Thank you, Mike and Tanaike for the efforts. Genius work! Please forgive me if my words were not clear and for all the trouble.