# Events are getting added to two default calendar - mine as well other users of the sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

Here's the code which lets users to put details of events in cells and they tick the box and event gets added. The solution is put up by Mike Steelson.
Link - [Add calendar event with the help of checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71359532/add-calendar-event-with-the-help-of-checkbox)

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('⇩ M E N U ⇩')
    .addItem(' Set up ...', 'myTriggerSetup')
    .addToUi();
}
function myTriggerSetup() {
  var ssID = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId()
  if (!isTrigger('onSpeEdit')) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('onSpeEdit').forSpreadsheet(ssID).onEdit().create();
  }
}
function isTrigger(funcName) {
  var r = false;
  if (funcName) {
    var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
    var allHandlers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < allTriggers.length; i++) {
      allHandlers.push(allTriggers[i].getHandlerFunction());
    }
    if (allHandlers.indexOf(funcName) > -1) {
      r = true;
    }
  }
  return r;
}
function onSpeEdit(e) {
  var rg = e.range;
  if (rg.getRow() == 4 && rg.isChecked() && rg.getSheet().getName() === "Course") {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Course');
    var start = new Date(rg.offset(-2,0).getValue()).getTime();
    var end = new Date(rg.offset(-1,0).getValue()).getTime();
    var name = rg.offset(-3,0).getValue();
    var calend = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
    calend.createEvent(name, new Date(start), new Date(end));
    rg.uncheck();
  }
}
```

**Issue:**
Events are getting added to my default calendar as well as user's calendar too.

**Requirement:** It should get added to default calendar of the user who is entering details and clicking on the checkbox

**Edit 1:**.
Solution [1] by Mike.
var calendName = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName('somebody')

I created a list on sheet with the names of default calendars of all users (like Alex Ab, John Cd, Ewel BM...) and changed the two lines of code this way but events were not getting added.

```
var calend = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName('AA51')[0];
  calend.createEvent(name, new Date(start), new Date(end));
```

Solution[2] = Duplicate sheet and trying. It did not work

Solution [3] = Adding macro to a button worked. Also, there is no need for a trigger with this. I feel very nervous with triggers as they stop working all of a sudden. Will it be a good idea to add a button instead?
I have added Mike Steelson's code to a button and it working nice.

**Code for a button:**.

```
function calendar() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Course');
  var start = new Date(spreadsheet.getRange('U70').getValue()).getTime();
  var end = new Date(spreadsheet.getRange('X69').getValue()).getTime();
  var name = spreadsheet.getRange('U69').getValue()
  var calend = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  calend.createEvent(name, new Date(start), new Date(end));
    spreadsheet.getRange('X59').setValue('Hooray! Reminder is added to your calendar');
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    Utilities.sleep(5000);
    spreadsheet.getRange('x59').clearContent();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be 2 solutions

### solution #1

create multiple agendas within your own agenda with the names of people,

then change a little the script as follows,

```
function onSpeEdit(e) {
  var rg = e.range;
  if (rg.getRow() == 4 && rg.isChecked() && rg.getSheet().getName() === "Course") {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Course');
    var start = new Date(rg.offset(-2,0).getValue()).getTime();
    var end = new Date(rg.offset(-1,0).getValue()).getTime();
    var name = rg.offset(-3,0).getValue();
    var calendName = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(rg.offset(1,0).getValue());
    calendName[0].createEvent(name, new Date(start), new Date(end));
    rg.uncheck();
  }
}
```

and ask people to put their name as follows

[image]

you will get this
[image]

### solution #2

ask everyone to copy the spreadsheet and thus create a new spreadsheet for them

if you need to synchronize use importrange

if you need to read, ask to share the agenda

Comment: Intelligent solution as always. I have 5 users and I will create 5 calendar and let respective user subscribe to them. That's amazing solution. But Mike, if my users forget to change the name then they won't see in their calendar. It will go to other calendar. Also, one extra field for them. I know we can enforce selecting that field with some validation check. Given my limited skills, I will prefer your "non-trigger solution" which I have put in the question part as "Code for button" for now as triggers are very unreliable. Thank you so much for this.

Comment: You are intelligent as well as very helpful (rare combination). God bless you with lots of intelligence. I feel blessed to get solutions so fast. Please accept my words as my gratitude and thanksgiving for all the help.