# Today custom function stops working in all google spreadsheets, any idea why?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

There are many threads, that custom function in google sheets "Loading" error. I have tried to find the answer, but I can't figure out, why it happens 'today'. Until now it was working fine, since 2 years.

Comment: No one can help with these info only. Please share an example.

Comment: Is your custom function using `IMPORTHTML`? There's a known issue that's currently causing the "loading" error for some users. 

https://support.google.com/docs/thread/153637852?hl=en